# How to transfer songs from Ubuntu PC into iPod touch 5g

Tags: 15.04, rhythmbox, music, ipod

I'm having a hard time trying to find a good solution to this problem.

I want to transfer songs to my iPod touch 5g just like I can through iTunes in Windows. Is there any method/workaround for this ?

I'm asking this question again because all other guides/questions are old and are not very practical at this point of time.

Any help including links to similar questions or any software/methods are very welcome.

Current setup: Ubuntu 15.04 (with Unity) and an iPod touch 5g (iOS 8.4 not jailbroken)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to follow this tutorial:

[Youtube-Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIn1oYa10J0)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Will do so, but didn't have the time and thought a fast answer - answered instantly - would be nice.